# What does "cat -" means in this command: cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh user@hostname "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Tags: unix

I saw the following command

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh user@hostname "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

another variation:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

What does "cat -" means ? and how does that actually helps to prepend a public key to a list of authorized key.

**sources**:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
http://www.davidgrant.ca/copy_ssh_public_key_to_server_in_one_line

Comment: Read the [**man-page**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) for it.  It is short for *concatenate*.  It says, *"With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command:

```
cat -
```

does a cat of the stdin

Eg:

```
$ cat > /test.txt
here goes some text into 
the file
```

[Ctrl]-[D] key combination to quit cat

to view file content:

```
cat test.txt
```

Hence,

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

means take content of id_rsa.pub PIPE to ssh command, and cat the stdin content and append it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server

More example:

```
$ cat Desktop/p.txt | cat - > /tmp/t.txt
$ cat /tmp/t.txt
```

*make sure that p.txt contains some text though.*

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `-` is unnecessary in this case. If invoked with no arguments, the `cat` command reads from its standard input anyway, so `cat -` could be replaced by `cat`. The `-` argument can be useful if you want it to read *both* from one or more named files and from standard input: `cat file1 - file2`